# Flash builder:Strange behavior on Datagrid

Tags: flash, apache-flex, datagrid

this problem has driven me crazy and I really need you guys help.

I have a datagrid showing data that is queried from mysql. I am trying to add a new row to my datagrid if the users add new record to the database. In other words, I want datagrid to reflect the uploaded data in the database. The datagrid seems to work ONLY on the first record I added. If I try to add a second record, the new row will be added but it ALSO change the first row to the newly updated record. I know it's a bit hard to understand so I draw a picture here.

```
DATAGRID

id   name     number
1    test1     111
2    test2     222
```

Lets say I add a new record and the datagrid will be

```
id   name     number
1    test1     111
2    test2     222
3    test3     333  //new record, works fine.
```

but if I add another record, it will become

```
id   name     number
1    test1     111
2    test2     222
4    test4     444  //old record, the values change to the newest record.
4    test4     444  //new record, but also change the previous record
```

If I add another record again, it will become

```
id   name     number
1    test1     111
2    test2     222
5    test5     555  //first record, the values change to the newest record.
5    test5     555  //second record, the values change to the newest record.
5    test5     555  //newest record, change the previous 2 records
```

I have done anything I could think of to debug but still no luck.
The following are my codes:

```
// my php data service
<s:CallResponder id="addResult" result="addResult_resultHandler(event)" />

<script>

        //The handler after the user click ADD button

        protected function addBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var newData:object = new Object();  
                newData.test1=formField1.text;
                newData.test2=formField2.text;
                newData.test3=formField3.text;
                newData.test4=formField4.text;


                            addResult.token=Service.createJob(newData);



            }





  //the result handler for data service. 
        protected function addResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
                {
                           //jobData is my dataProvider in my datagrid component 
                          //not sure why addItem() would mess me up so badly...
                           //newData is an Object created after user click the update    
                           //button

                           jobDG.jobData.addItem(newData);          
                }


    Mxml

    <components:dataGridPanel  id="jobDG"
                               jobData="{getJobsResult.lastResult}"/>


    My datagrid component

    mxml
        <s:DataGrid id="dg" editable="true" x="5" y="3" width="734" height="253">
            <s:columns>
              <s:ArrayList>

                <s:GridColumn dataField="test1" headerText="text1">      
                            </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="test2" headerText="text2">            
                            </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="test3" headerText="text3">  
                            </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="test4" headerText="text4">  
                            </s:GridColumn>
               </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
            <s:typicalItem>
            <fx:Object text1="aaaaa" text2="bbbbb" text3="ccccc" text4="dddddd">  
                     </fx:Object>
            </s:typicalItem>
             <s:AsyncListView list="{jobData}" />
        </s:DataGrid>
```

I am really desperate now. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't your real code, is it? It couldn't work: you're accessing a variable 'newData' in 'addResult_resultHandler()' while it was declared locally in 'addBtn_clickHandler()'. It shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other commenters that your posted code is unlikely to be what you're actually using, but I think it does show the seeds of what your problem is.  I think you have an instance variable called newData that you instantiate at the top of your Class, rather than in the addBtn_clickHandler function.

The first time it works, because you've never added it to the collection before.  When you click the button again, I suspect you're simply changing the properties on the same object, then adding it to the collection in your result handler (rather than looking at the event's data to get the new object that has been returned from the database).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super good with Flex/Flash-Builder, but I am good with actionscript. Your code looks a little truncated/simplified to me? Can you post the complete functions?

I'm also not great with DataProviders, but I understand the concept and have used DataGrids before. I'd double check the [AS3 docs on DataGrids](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html): It looks like every example there defines the provider in its entirety first, then applies it to the grid. You may have to set up events with some special listeners, or even destroy and rebuild the whole grid after updating your data? I'm assuming it's only a front-end display issue, but without more code we can't rule out a backend-logic issue.

Comment: -1. This should have been a comment, not an answer. Because it does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: I tried to help, but I guess you're right. It's a hard question to answer without more complete code. I'll post this type of response as a comment in the future. I'm a noob when it comes to answering questions on stackoveflow, but I want to contribute where I can. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: read the [faq], it'll do you good. Nice that you're here to help, you'll find we all are. However, posting answers that aren't really answers reduces the quality of the forum, so I strongly suggest you check out the [faq]